# Infinitely recursive call is executed despite having stop condition, since the parameters don't advance

Tags: c++, recursion, structure

I have a recursive function which I need to scroll through a group of structures, that are in the form of sub-lists one into another consecutively.

**structure of nodes**

```
struct Intake{ // this is a sublist
   int id;
   string month;
   int intakeEnergy;
   struct Intake * next;
   struct electricalDevices * firstED;
   struct intakeEnergySector * linkIES;
   Intake(int i, string m, int iE){
       id = i;
       month = m;
       intakeEnergy = iE;
       next = NULL;
       firstED = NULL;
   }
};

struct Home{   // this is a sublist
   int code;
   string address;
   struct Home * next;
   struct Intake * firstI;
   struct homePersons * linkHP;
   Home(int c, string ad){
       code = c;
       address = ad;
       next = NULL;
       firstI = NULL;
   }
};
```

**Call & Recursive Function**

```
int recursiveTraversal(int idLocality, struct Home *homeToRoam, struct Intake *intakeToRoam, int idElectricalDevice){
    if (homeToRoam == NULL)
        return 0;
    else{
        intakeToRoam = homeToRoam -> firstI;

        if (intakeToRoam == NULL)
            return 0 + (recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam -> next, intakeToRoam, idElectricalDevice));
        else{
            struct electricalDevices * temp = searchED(idLocality, homeToRoam -> code, intakeToRoam -> id, idElectricalDevice);

            if (temp == NULL){
                return 0 + (recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam, intakeToRoam -> next, idElectricalDevice));
            }else{

                return (temp -> intakeEnergyPerHour) + (recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam, intakeToRoam -> next, idElectricalDevice));
            }
        }
    }
}

void monthlyConsumptionOfADeviceInALocality(int idLocality, int idElectricalDevice){
    struct Locality * localityX = searchL(idLocality);
    int monthlyConsumption;

    if (localityX == NULL){
        cout<<"\nThe Locality doesn't exist...\n";
        return ;
    }else{
        monthlyConsumption = recursiveTraversal(idLocality , localityX -> firstH, NULL, idElectricalDevice);
        cout<<"Monthly Consumption: "<<monthlyConsumption;
    }
}
```

Here is the function's code, the problem is for example, when I assign the homeToRome node, I write localityX -> firstH into the parameter, and into the recursive function, feel the same, assigning the first node of each of the sublists.

**Line of increase**

> return 0 + (recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam, **intakeToRoam -> next**, idElectricalDevice));

But when I increase the intakeToRoam to the next node in the recursive call, it set the same.

Even if I print the value memory, intakeToRoam is a different value compare to intakeToRoam -> next.

In advance thank you very much, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite recursion because you always reset `intakeToRoam` with this line:

```
intakeToRoam = homeToRoam->firstI;
```

If you remove this line you now have a problem of identifying the start and end of iterating the `intakeToRoam` list. Easiest way to fix this is to keep a `NULL` `intakeToRoam` mean to start iterating and have a manual check for the end of the list in the function, something like:

```
int recursiveTraversal(int idLocality, struct Home *homeToRoam, struct Intake *intakeToRoam, int idElectricalDevice){
    if (homeToRoam == NULL)
        return 0;
    else {

        if (intakeToRoam == NULL)
            return 0 + (recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam, homeToRoam->firstI, idElectricalDevice));
        else {
            struct electricalDevices * temp = searchED(idLocality, homeToRoam -> code, intakeToRoam -> id, idElectricalDevice);
            int consumption = 0;

            if (temp != NULL) consumption = temp -> intakeEnergyPerHour;

            if (intakeToRoam->next != NULL)
                return consumption + recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam, intakeToRoam -> next, idElectricalDevice);
            else
                return consumption + recursiveTraversal(idLocality, homeToRoam->next, NULL, idElectricalDevice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that I feel stupid, I mean if it was restarting the value xD
Thanks uesp!

Comment: I just realized with this code you will still run into an infinite loop if `homeToRoam->firstI == NULL` so you will want to check for that case as well.